# How to specify a table type using EF6 Fluent API for MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

So I am using EF6's Fluent API to specify entity properties in my code first application. However I would like to specify a table type for one of my entities, is it possible to do this via the api?

**ApplicationDbContext:**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime RememberMeTimeOut { get; set; }
        public int CentralPermissionUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserLogs> UserLogs { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {

            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DBContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserLogs> UserLogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SupplierArchive> SupplierArchive { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuStatsSummary> MenuStatsSummary { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pot> Pots { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PotDupeStandards> PotDupeStandards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DupeStandards> DupeStandards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DupeStandardMapping> DupeStandardMapping { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DupeData> DupeData { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            #region Application User
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(255);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(255);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.CentralPermissionUserID).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.UserLogs)
                .WithRequired(u => u.User)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(u => u.Email)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UQ_Email") { IsUnique = true }));

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(u => u.UserName)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UQ_UserName") { IsUnique = true }));
            #endregion
```

So lets say I wanted to set the `ApplicationUser` table to use the `MyISAM` table engine, how can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by `engine` ?

Comment: MySQL has multiple table engines which affect how the table works and it's purpose. Eg InnoDB is the default and another is the Archive table engine which basically just compresses the memory at the expense of performance and other key table features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to create a migration and then write your own Sql commands in the Up method like so:

```
Sql("DROP TABLE Badger");
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot do that**.B'cos you can use `Fluent API` to configure your domain classes.But `fluent API` doesn't know anything about the specific database provider's details.It is a generic API to map your `POCO` classes to `tables` and its `columns`.

`MYSQL` is a relational database provider and it's having lot of provider specific components.As an example it's having different table engines. such as `InnoDB`,`MyISAM` and etc.But Fluent Api is just a mapper which doesn't know anything about the database provider's specific implementations.